# Does Lebesgue measure $ f $ is 0?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

suppose $ f:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d] $ be a function of one-to-one and onto and continuous and $ m$ be Lebesgue measure on $ [a,b] $. Do the function $f$ image null subset of $[a,b]$ to the null set?

Comment: If $m(A) = 0$ for every $A \subset [a,b]$, then $m([a,b]) = 0$; thus $a = b$ and $f(A)$ consists of a single point.

Comment: If $m(A) = 0$ for every $A \subset [a,b]$, then $b \leq a$...

Comment: The Cantor function maps a set of measure zero to a set of non-zero measure, if that is what you are trying to ask.

Comment: And take the sum of the Cantor function with the identity function to obtain an example that's one-to-one.